# How can I refer to my actual ether balance in a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, private-blockchain, balances

Not the tokens created in a contract but the balance which I allocate in the genesis.

Comment: you are using web3.js ? or what framework for the communication with the blockchain? And if you can put some code.

Comment: currently using the command line interface of geth.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the balance of an account within a contract then use `<address>.balance`.

Comment: when I use this with my default account **eth.accounts[0]** it gives me a very high value and does not match the return value of `eth.getBalance()`.
I think it is because of the datatype. How can I solve this?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code, but perhaps it's a unit issue? I know in solidity, `<address>.balance` returns the amount of ether in wei, where 1 ether = 10^8 wei